# Office365 API Error "Mailbox database change detected;"

Tags: office365api

Occasionally when sending an email through the Office365 API, we get an error back:

excerpt:

```
{"httpCode":503,"headers":"HTTP/1.1 100 Continue\r\n\r\nHTTP/1.1 503 
Service UnavailableX-MS-Diagnostics: Routing Validation; Mailbox 
database change detected; moved from database 31f16b42-8c32-43a3-a05f- 
f554bb4c579f to 78f2e7a1-e65f-4148-8be4-b98ac0635fdf\r\nX- 
BEServerRoutingError: Mailbox database change detected; moved from 
database 31f16b42-8c32-43a3-a05f-f554bb4c579f to 78f2e7a1-e65f-4148- 
8be4-b98ac0635fdf"}
```

Does anyone know why this happens,its annoying when the client thinks your app is faulty, when its actually an error within the Office API which causes it.

Answer (score 1):

You just made a call in the middle of a re-balancing operation.  Just retry your call.  For things like this, you shouldn't need to show them to the client.

Comment: David, do you know how long a "re-balancing" should take?  We see these errors a lot, is this expected and consider "transient" (can we just retry in 1, or 2 seconds - or do we need to retry in 5-10 minutes?

Comment: It should be pretty quick.  I would do a ramp up on retry.  Maybe 5 sec, then 10 sec, 20, etc...